# Start Skype on boot with crontab

Tags: cron

I includes these entries yet Skype don't manage to start on boot:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/./skype
@reboot /usr/bin/skype
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this using `cron`? It will probably be possible, but it's not straightforward and is certainly not worth the effort. Why not add `skype` to your startup applications?

Comment: Skype was just one example to test the function for starting commands.

Comment: In that case it's a very bad example since it is a graphical program and depends on all sorts of other things being loaded for it to run. What is it you're actually trying to achieve here? Do you want to run GUI programs with `cron`? Do you just want to run GUI programs on reboot? Non-GUI programs on reboot? Please [edit] and explain what your final goal is, I doubt that `cron` is the right way to do it here.

Comment: Just to add, when `cron` runs tasks, by default, it doesn't let the application show any window, since it doesn't provide the same environment variables you would have in a normal terminal. You could set the environment variable that lets applications display GUI windows, but if you're using it with the `@reboot` command, you're better off just using startup applications.